# how to pass value and run function between two siblings component React

Tags: react-native

[image]

How to pass value and run function between two siblings component. I am using React , Hooks

Items list exist in CreateArea.jsx component, which I want to delete an item from.
The delete button exist in  Note.jsx component

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this.. but I find Context API to work great if the app is not too complicated. Its a simple process:

1. Configure a provider
2. Configure a consumer and read/write data

### Configure a provider

```
//App.js
const [data, setData] = useState()

let contextValue = {
    data: data,
    handleChange: (d) => setData(d)
}

return (
    <RootContext.Provider value ={contextValue}>
        <AppContainer/>
    </RootContext.Provider>
)
```

### Configure consumer

```
//SomeComponent.js - you can use consumer in any number of components
return(
    <RootContext.Consumer>
        {(handleChange, data) => {
            handleChange({key: value})
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
        }}
    </RootContext.Consumer>
)
```

More information can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)